# Grunt tool for optimizing webfont files

Tags: web, gruntjs, webfonts

Is there a automated tool for optimizing webfont files (.otf, .eot)?
By optimization here I mean subsetting, removing metadata and anyhing else that could make the file smaller. I would be great if it could become a part of a grunt build chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [grunt-font-optimizer](https://github.com/ActivearkJWT/grunt-font-optimizer) it can remove symbols and [grunt-ziti](https://github.com/caiguanhao/grunt-ziti) which can do the subsetting.

Answer (score 0):

[fontoptim](https://github.com/sapegin/fontoptim) seems to be a mighty tool that should base64 encode fonts and loads them async but unfortunately I couldn't test it yet.